# OpenShift - Expose pod with Websockets end-point outside of cluster

Tags: node.js, docker, web-services, websocket, openshift

I have a Websockets server in NodeJS that is to be deployed on-to OpenShift. This end-point will be accessed over the Internet with a CLI e.g. `wscat`, `websocat`, etc. I am unable to connect in the following attempts.

What is the way to expose a `ws` end-point from a `pod` to outside the cluster?

In all the experiments, access is with `wscat -c`.

### Experiment 1

- Service Type: `ClusterIp`
- Service Port: `8080`
- Route: `http`
- Access URL: `ws://` and `http://`
- Result: `error: Unexpected server response: 503`
- Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632140/919480

### Experiment 2

- Service Type: `ClusterIp`
- Service Port: `8000`
- Route: `http`
- Access URL: `ws://` and `http://`
- Result: `error: Unexpected server response: 503`
- Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30648060/919480

### Experiment 3

- Service Type: `LoadBalancer`
- Service Port: `8080`
- Access URL: `ws://` and `http://`
- Result: `error: socket hang up`

### Experiment 4

- Service Type: `LoadBalancer`
- Service Port: `8000`
- Access URL: `ws://` and `http://`
- Result: `error: socket hang up`

### Experiment 5

- Access from other pod in cluster as `ws://svcname.namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080`
- Result: `ECONNREFUSED`

### Experiment 6

- Access from within container as `ws://localhost:8080`
- Result: Works.

[Source code](https://github.com/ChrisPhillips-cminion/PlayingWithWebSockets/blob/master/server/index.js) for all the experiments I ran.

`server.js`

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws')

const sleep = require("sleep").sleep
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  port: process.env.WS_PORT // Set to various values based on experiments
})
console.log(`WS Started`)
var stack  = []
wss.on('connection', ws => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ws))
  console.log(`Got Connection`)
  ws.send("Connection Established");
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(ws))
  ws.on('message', message => {
    console.log(`Received message => ${message}`)
  })
})
wss.on('error',ws => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ws))
})
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10 as build

COPY . .
RUN npm i

# Port number changed as per the experiment
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Deployment YAML - without `route`

`deploy-lb.yaml`

Port numbers are changed based on experiment.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ws-so-q
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ws-so-q
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ws-so-q
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ws-so-q
          image: ....
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          env:
            - name: WS_PORT
              value: 9090
      ports:
        - name: ws
          containerPort: 9090
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ...
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ws-so-q
  labels:
    app: ws-so-q
spec:
  ports:
    - name: ws
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9090
      targetPort: ws
  selector:
    app: ws-so-q
  type: LoadBalancer
    sessionAffinity: None
    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

Deployment YAML - with `route`

`deploy-route.yaml`

Port numbers are changed based on experiment.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ws-so-q
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ws-so-q
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ws-so-q
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ws-so-q
          image: ....
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          env:
            - name: WS_PORT
              value: 9090
      ports:
        - name: ws
          containerPort: 9090
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ...
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ws-so-q
  labels:
    app: ws-so-q
spec:
  ports:
    - name: ws
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9090
      targetPort: ws
  selector:
    app: ws-so-q
---
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ws-so-q
  labels:
    app: ws-so-q
  annotations:
    openshift.io/host.generated: 'true'
spec:
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: ws-so-q
  port:
    targetPort: ws
  tls:
    termination: edge
  wildcardPolicy: None
```

Comment: It seems in the above examples you have a bit of a mess with the port numbers, sometimes you are using 8080, sometimes 9090, so make sure you stay consistent. Might also be an issue with the loadbalancer in front of your OpenShift cluster, so you may need to contact your administrator. In general, WebSockets work in OpenShift out-of-the-box, I was able to confirm your configuration (https://pastebin.com/FHgJtMVt) on my cluster and it worked as expected: `$ websocat -k wss://ws-so-q-ws-so.apps.example.com
Connection Established
{"_events":{},"_eventsCount":1,"readyState":1,"pr[..]`

Comment: It's not a mess; it's trial and error. The port numbers are consistent per experiment. What was the configuration of the LB in your OpenShift?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, as noted make sure the ports are either all 8080 or all 9090 to be sure it is not a port-numbering problem. I am using a HAProxy-based Load Balancer in front of my OpenShift cluster with a generic default configuration, which allows WebSocket connections to the backend. The OpenShift Router supports WebSockets, so make sure the Load Balancer in front of your cluster allows WebSockets.

Comment: Since I'm facing the same issue trying to run mosquitto over ws on openshift ... what was your final solution